# How to get text from TextBox & put it inside anchor tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a webpage where I have to get text from TextBox after it has text and put it inside anchor tag like this

```
<a href="value here">
```

I tried this solution but it works with button click only and i'm not able to set value between href="here"

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<button onclick="myFunction()" name="btnView">View</button>
<a href="http://urlhere/valueFromTextbox">Name</a>
```

Javascript :

```
function myFunction() {
var test = document.getElementById("name").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test;
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: where is the code where you set the href?

Answer (score 3):

You could listen for input- or change-events on the input-field and set the href-attribute of your anchor in the handler.

For example:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('name');
const anchor = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

input.oninput = () => { 
    anchor.href = input.value; 
};
```

```html
Enter href: <input id="name">
<a href="">Click here</a>
```

Comment: It's working perfect Andre. But the problem is not giving preview of the URL. Why so?

Comment: What do you mean by preview of the URL?

Comment: Like as a preview that URL has an image but as the value of URL is changing dynamically the way you showed, it's not loading it's preview. But originally it has link preview facility. Can you please help? Just like facebook has it's link preview.

Comment: This behavior is not standard and you need more JavaScript to achieve it. If you have a working example, update the question and I will try to help you, otherwise this sounds like another issue on its own. By googling 'link preview js' I found some promising links...

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is setting innerHTML which is wrong. Anchor tags "href" is an attribute. You have to set it as an attribute, not innerHTML. Try this instead.

```
var test = document.getElementById("name").value;
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", text);
```

Comment: It's not working @shubham-gupta . Can you please help. on button click the url bar just append. anchor tag doesnt have that value.


Is this proper code :

var test = document.getElementById("name").value;
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", test);

Answer (score 0):

try this it can be useful:

for the html:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<a id="anchor" href="">Link</a>
<button type="button" onclick="foo();">Change link</button>
```

javascript function:

```
function foo(){
  getHref = document.getElementById("name").value;

  document.getElementById("anchor").href = "https://"+getHref;

}
```

Comment: It works fine for me but i add ```https://``` to the text so the user must not add it again, after clicking the button link must appear, i also use different id for the anchor

Answer (score 0):

Href is an attribute, if you want to change it you need to change the attribute using attr(). Create a listener to fire when the text box has input and change the href attribute